# Write parameter inside BCP query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
execute master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT lat.Custcode,lat.NoRekDebet,Format(lat.TotalLockAmount ,''#0'') TotalLockAmount FROM Lock_Amount_Trx lat WHERE lat.Id = "20200428145858" AND lat.LockStatus ="Active"" queryout D:\yy\xx\\DATA.LOCK.PBK.AKTIF_20200428145858.dat -U 111 -P xxx /S WIN-GPVTBG10EBJ -t"~" -T -c'
```

I get error like this:

[image]

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. The Object doesn't exist. My guess if you're connecting the to wrong database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please specify the database and schema name (fully qualified) while providing the table name. Also, use the proper quotes while providing the values.

```
execute master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT lat.Custcode,lat.NoRekDebet,Format(lat.TotalLockAmount ,''#0'') TotalLockAmount FROM dbname.schemaname.Lock_Amount_Trx lat WHERE lat.Id = ''20200428145858'' AND lat.LockStatus =''Active''" queryout D:\yy\xx\\DATA.LOCK.PBK.AKTIF_20200428145858.dat -U 111 -P xxx -S WIN-GPVTBG10EBJ -t"~" -T -c'
```